# How to read a bin file to a byte array?

Tags: java, file-io, arrays

I have a bin file that I need to convert to a byte array.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
File f = new File("notification.bin");
is = new FileInputStream(f);

long length = f.length();

/*if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    // File is too large
}*/

// Create the byte array to hold the data
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

// Read in the bytes
int offset = 0;
int numRead = 0;
while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
    offset += numRead;
}

// Ensure all the bytes have been read in
if (offset < bytes.length) {
    throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+f.getName());
}
```

But it's not working...

Kaddy

Comment: I fixed that for you.  Please try to actually format questions you post so they are intelligent and legible.

Comment: In what way is it not working? What is the File class you are using? Why not use the standard std::ifstream?

Comment: Probably because it's C# and not C++

Comment: That's not C# - I believe it's Java.

Comment: It certainly looks a heck of a lot more like Java than C#, anyway. I've edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: It was tagged C++, but that seems to have been removed. I give up!

Comment: Yeah, and it was tagged C# when I commented. Oh well, my bad! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this

```
public byte[] readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    byte[] data = new byte[4096];
    int count = inputStream.read(data);
    while(count != -1)
    {
        dos.write(data, 0, count);
        count = inputStream.read(data);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Btw, do you want a Java code or C++ code. Seeing the code in your question, I assumed it to be a java code and hence gave a java answer to it

Comment: What's that `DataOutputStream` about?

Comment: +1 That's a nice catch Tom, ByteArrayOutputStream would suffice in this case, where we just read bytes and write bytes. If we were to write primitive types in addition DataOutputStream might be needed

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using a memory mapped file.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301923/reading-binary-files-without-buffering-the-whole-file-into-memory-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to do it just that way, maybe simplify what you're doing.

Doing *everything* in the for loop may seem like a very slick way of doing it, but it's shooting yourself in the foot when you need to debug and don't immediately see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a simple solution is:

```
InputStream is = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[4096];  // A larger buffer size would probably help
int count; 
while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
    os.write(data, 0, count);
}
byte[] result = os.toByteArray();
```

If the input is a file, we can preallocate a byte array of the right size:

```
File f = ...
long fileSize = f.length();
if (fileSize > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    // file too big
}
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
byte[] data = new byte[fileSize];
if (is.read(data)) != data.length) {
    // file truncated while we were reading it???
}
```

However, there is probably a more efficient way to do this task using NIO.

Answer (score 0):

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478455/how-to-grab-byte-of-an-image-in-java/1478544#1478544) I read from an URL

You could modify it so the InputStream is from a File instead of a URLConnection.

Something like:

```
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("your.binary.file");

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte [] buffer               = new byte[ 1024 ];

    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = inputStream.read(buffer))) {
       output.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    inputStream.close();
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Try open source library [apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/)
**IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)**
You are not the first and not the last developer who needs to read a file, no need to reinvent it each time.